# Accessing state object properties returning null

Tags: javascript, react-redux

I'm using useSelector hook to access my state, but getting null error when trying to access the properties of the object, any idea on this please?

const currentState = useSelector(state =>  state.auth);

console log prints out the auth details and I can see all the auth object properties;
console.log('my current state is', currentState );
But below lines throwing error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null
const id = currentState.id;
console.log('my id is', id );

Answer (score 0):

If the `auth` state is being filled in asynchronously (i.e. a dispatch doing a network call to fill the state in), the initial state for `auth` will be null. This can be resolved by doing a null check before trying to access `id`.

If you have support for optional chaining...

```js
const Component = () => {
  const currentState = useSelector(state => state.auth);

  // If you have support for optional chaining
  const id = currentState?.id;
}
```

otherwise

```js
const Component = () => {
  const currentState = useSelector(state => state.auth);

  // If you have support for optional chaining
  const id = currentState != null && currentState.id;
}
```